# Complexity simplification for complexity that consists of partial multiplication

Tags: asymptotics, complexity-theory

For the algorithm that I have written the complexity is something like:

a * e(A) + b * e(B) + b * e(C) + ...

Where a represents the instance count of some node A and e(A) the edges outgoing of node A. Also if we say:

a + b + c + ... = n

e(A) + e(B) + e(C) + ... = e

Then I can say that the complexity is 
O(n*e)

Is there a way to make it tighter? The values for e(...) are usually not too high so doing e*n and counting all edges for each node seems a bit of a high overstatement. This seems like a common situation so I was wondering if there was a good known way to express this complexity to convey that it is not actually that extreme.

Comment: Can you help us understand what "instance count" means?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry. So here, the nodes would kind of represent tasks and instance count would be the number times the task gets executed. So number of occurrence of the node in other words. Each time a task occurs the number of edges is the same and all edges would be utilized. So in other words i(A)*e(A) + i(B)*e(B) if we would express it a bit differently where A,B,.. are tasks i() is instance count, e() is edge count for the task/node/job

Comment: We prefer that you [edit] the question to include all relevant information in the question and to make it read well for someone who encounters the question for the first time.  We don't want people to have to read the comments to understand what you're asking.  Thank you!

Comment: If $a = n$ and $e(A) = e$ then $ae(A) = ne$. Does that answer your question?